# Is it possible to control label text color independently in each of the templates in Formview?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a formview with the standard three templates, Item, EditItem and InsertItem.  I am using labels in various fields whereby I control the text that is displayed based upon data in an sql table (no problem).  The same label ID number is used in each of the templates for the same field (Label1 is used for the value field in each template).  Is it possible to independently control the color of the displayed text?  That is, I would like to change the color to red in only the EditItem and InsertItem templates while retaining the black color in the Item template.  I have an idea that I can use the ModeChanged event to accomplish this but have had no luck getting it to work.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
Protected Sub FormView1_ModeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView1.ModeChanged

    Dim conCString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conCString").ConnectionString
    Dim lbl24 As Label = FormView1.FindControl("Label24")
    Dim sqlConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conCString").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection
    If FormView1.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Edit Then
        Dim querystring As String = "SELECT [DisplayName], [BuildRules] FROM [BuildFields] WHERE ([TableID] = N'Capacitors') AND (ColumnID = N'Value') ORDER BY [ColumnID]"
        sqlConnection.Open()
        Dim command24 As New SqlCommand(querystring, sqlConnection)
        Dim reader24 As SqlDataReader = command24.ExecuteReader()
        While reader24.Read()
            lbl24.Text = reader24(0)
            If reader24(1) = 255 Then
                lbl24.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Else
                lbl24.ForeColor = Color.Black
            End If
        End While
        sqlConnection.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am guessing this WPF related; if so you might want to add the appropriate tag to get the right attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move this to formview1_databound and use if statements to determine the current mode and set colors accordingly.